# Counting duplicates within a list, and putting that number into a sublist?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been looking but can't figure this out.

So I have a function that finds prime factors.
The prime factors of 1,000 are `[2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5]`.
I want a function to convert this list to be like this:
`[[2,3], [5,3]]`

I want to show the powers, rather than repeated factors.

I just can't seam to make it work.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by `I want to show the powers, rather than repeated factors`.  The powers **will be** the repeated factors.

Comment: Sorry about that. I wanted to display 2^4 rather than 2*2*2*2 so in the list I stored [[2,3], [5,3]] rather than [2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5]

Answer (score 3):

Try the following, using [`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
from collections import Counter

lst = [2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5]
[[x, y] for x, y in Counter(lst).items()]

=> [[2, 3], [5, 3]]
```

The above has the additional advantage that the factors in the list can appear in any order - they don't need to be sorted.

Comment: @GeoStyx Glad to hear that! If this answer was helpful for you, please don't forget to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it by clicking on the check mark to the left ;)

Comment: You could also use `map(list, Counter(lst).iteritems())`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `collections.Counter`, you can do:

```
>>> lst = [2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5]
>>> [[x, lst.count(x)] for x in set(lst)]
[[2, 3], [5, 3]]
>>>
```

---

Here is a test of speed using [`timeit.timeit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html):

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>>
>>> # Oscar's
>>> test = """
... from collections import Counter
... lst = [2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5]
... [[x, y] for x, y in Counter(lst).items()]
... """
>>> timeit(test, number=10000)
0.323039660068531
>>>
>>> # Mine
>>> test = """
... lst = [2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5]
... [[x, lst.count(x)] for x in set(lst)]
... """
>>> timeit(test, number=10000)
0.04072053850418911
>>>
```

Comment: Which is better/faster?

Comment: @GeoStyx - Well, I tested 10000 cycles of each using `timeit.timeit` (see my edit) and I got a better time for mine.  Mine also doesn't need an import.  However, I would _strongly_ suggest you run your own tests to backup mine.  What works in one place could _not_ work somewhere else.

Comment: @iCodez, please, test it on both `range(2000)`, `range(20000)`, `random.sample(range(20000), 20000)`. Comparing speed of two containers on a 5-elements-long list is not adequate.

Comment: @kroolik - I ran more tests and mine was consistently faster as long as the list length was < 50.  Now, that sounds bad...until you realize he is working with prime factorization.  And, I _sincerely_ doubt he will have a 2000 number prime factorization.  However, I will say Oscar's solution is a lot faster with large lists.

Comment: @kroolik - In other words, I think mine works better for his needs.

Comment: @iCodez, you are right that you'll rarely encounter a 2000-long factorization. What I meant was that doing benchmarks on small data size is inadequate.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from math import sqrt

def factor(n):
    i = 2
    limit = sqrt(n)    
    while i <= limit:
      if n % i == 0:
        yield i
        n = n / i
        limit = sqrt(n)   
      else:
        i += 1
    if n > 1:
        yield n

def pfac(num):
    d=defaultdict(int)
    for f in factor(num):
        d[f]+=1

    terms=[]
    for e in sorted(d.keys()):
        if d[e]>1:
            terms.append('{:,}^{}'.format(e,d[e]))
        else:
            terms.append('{:,}'.format(e))

    print ' * '.join(terms),'=','{:,}'.format(num)           

pfac(1000)
```

Prints `2^3 * 5^3 = 1,000`

And works with sizable numbers:

```
pfac(1000**12-1)
# 3^4 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 19 * 37 * 101 * 9,901 * 52,579 * 333,667 * 999,999,000,001 = 999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999
```